# I am returning Json as string from api but on client in javascript it's coming as object

Tags: string, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.1

I am migrating from .net framework to .net core 2.1 and I have migrated my API controller to Web API controller in 2.1 core . But here behaviour is different due to which I have to change my client side code which I don't want to change . I am returning JSON as string from api but on client side it's not getting received as string , its getting converted to object when I receive back on client . I want it as string only , otherwise I have to remove JSON.PARSE e

Here is the example code , consider dataset coming from somewhere which I am using in this code

```
[HTTPGet("[action]")]
public string GetData()
{
var result1 = JSONCONVERT.SerializeObject(new {Details =            dataset.tables[1]});

var result2 = JSONCONVERT.SerializeObject(new {Details = dataset.tables[2]});

var result = JSONCONVERT.SerializeObject(new []    {JSONCONVERT.DeSerializeObject(result1) ,    JSONCONVERT.DeSerializeObject(result2)}); 

return result;
}
```

So this result which I am sending back here to client , I expect same as string on client , but it is coming as object which is good but I need to do code changes in my client because earlier it was coming as string and we have parsed it. But now there is no need to parse with object on receiving end. Is there any way I can have string only? Because I do not want to make changes at 100 places and test the same.

Comment: It seems to be correct that you're sending it as JSON, but if you really don't want to change all your front end, you could just convert it to a string before sending it to the client

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON serializer itself, instead of the SerializeObject. That will allow you to control the output. Like so:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\json.txt"))
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, product);
    // {"ExpiryDate":new Date(1230375600000),"Price":0}
}
```